# При нажатии срабатывала одна часть кода, а при повторном вторая часть кода JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, функции

Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку работала первая часть кода.

```
check = genirateTasks()
const summ = check.reduce((partial_sum, a) => partial_sum + a, 0); 
console.log(summ);
```

А при повторном нажатии вторая часть кода.

```
if(taskAnswer.value == ){
console.log(1);
}else{
console.log(2);
}
```

Можно ли это сделать на чистом JS.

Вот весь код функции

```
function checkUserAnswer(){
check = genirateTasks()
const summ = check.reduce((partial_sum, a) => partial_sum + a, 0); 
console.log(summ);

if(taskAnswer.value == ){
  console.log(1);
}else{
  console.log(2);
  }
}
```

И ещеё **index.html**

```
<button onclick="checkUserAnswer()" class="btn-info" id="check-btn">Начать!</button>
```

Comment: Почему у вопроса метка Java ?

Comment: Подход не верный! Действия разные: один генерирует таск, другой проверяет. Соответственно и вызов должен быть разных функций - раз, и разных кнопок - два. А делать проверку ответа на кнопку Начать - совсем дикость

Comment: Просто у меня проблема, которую я не понимаю как решать, если делаешь 2 функции всё ломается.

Comment: А как делаете? А что значит ломается?

Comment: Это сложно объяснить без скриншотов, у вас есть телеграм или ещё что-то подобнее, я подробно там написашу, если у вас есть время.

Comment: Нет. Я пас) Попробуйте посидеть и сформулировать вопрос с проблемой и задать на стаке. Но вот то, что сейчас вы хотите сделать - не верных подход

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас сформулирую и задам на стаке.

Answer (score -2):

Вот как один из вариантов.

Для двух нажатий:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('click', foo);

function foo(){
  if(!this.classList.contains('active')){
    console.log('1-ая часть кода')
    
    ////код
    this.value = 'закончить'


    this.classList.add('active')

  }else{
     console.log('2-ая часть кода')
  
    this.value = 'Начать!'
    ////код
    this.classList.remove('active')
  
  }


}
```

```html
<body> 
        <input type="button" value="Начать!">

    </body>
```

Для двух нажатий + запрет.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('click', foo);

function foo(){
  if(!this.classList.contains('active')){
    console.log('1-ая часть кода')
    
    ////код
    this.value = 'закончить'


    this.classList.add('active')

  }else{
     console.log('2-ая часть кода')
  
    this.value = 'ОТКЛЮЧЕНО'
    ////код

    
    this.disabled = true
    
  }
  
}
```

```html
<body> 
        <input class="one" type="button" value="Начать!">
    </body>
```

Answer (score -2):

Имхо, самый простой способ, воспользоваться генератором, подробнее [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/generators).

Пример из документации:

```
function* generateSequence() {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  return 3;
}

let generator = generateSequence();

let one = generator.next();

alert(JSON.stringify(one)); // {value: 1, done: false}
```